# Buscar en base de datos usando javascript mediante un boton y agregar a una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una parte de mi programa que recibe el código de un producto mediante un input y al activar un botón desearía que busque en la DB y me recupere el nombre y su precio

adjunto imagen de el input y el botón
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del código de mi tabla

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table-body-venta">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Este es mi codigo en javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myText;
$("#codigo-producto-venta").on("keyup", function () {
    myText = $(this).val();
});

$("#agregar-producto-venta").on("click", function () {
    //en base a mytext (codigo del producto) buscar en la base de datos y agregar a la tabla
    var html = "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + myText + "</td>";
    html += "<td>buscar en la base de datos el nombre del producto</td>";
    html +=
        "<td>buscar en la base de datos el precio del producto</td></tr>";
    $(html).appendTo($("table:eq(0)").find("#table-body-venta"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

si entendí bien tu pregunta, entonces deseas usar ajax, de forma que te realice un request a tu base de datos sin recargar la página, y que esto te devuelva los datos de la base de datos.

Describiendo lo que hace este codigo, primero, agrega un `.addEventListener` al form donde tomo los datos, el cual tiene un `submit` de tal forma que al presionar el submit, se ejecute la función que he llamado `prueba`.
Luego de eso, creo la función `function prueba(e)`, la parte de `e.preventDefault();` me ayuda a evitar recargar  la página; la variable `var params` es donde guardo los parámetros que deseo enviar por método POST a mi controlador; en `xhr.open('POST', '/carrito', true);` el primer atributo es el método para hacer el request, el segundo es la ruta que me dirige al controlador, y el tercero es para decir si es asíncrono o síncrono.

```
document.getElementById('postForm{{$product->id}}').addEventListener('submit', prueba{{$product->id}});
        function prueba{{$product->id}}(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = document.getElementById({{$product->id}}).value;
            var params = "idproducto="+id+"&idcarrito="+{{$carrito_id[0]->id}};

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/carrito', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', "{{ csrf_token() }}");
            xhr.onload = function(){
                if(this.responseText){
                    document.getElementById("alertamal").innerHTML = "Lo sentimos, ha habido un error en la base de datos, por favor recargue la página.";
                    y.style.display =  "block";
                    $("#alertamal").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#alertamal").fadeOut(8000);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("alertabien").innerHTML = "¡FELICIDADES! Ha añadido correctamente su producto al carrito de compras";
                    x.style.display =  "block";
                    $("#alertabien").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#alertabien").fadeOut(8000);
                }
            }
            xhr.send(params);
        }
```